# What's the best way to display sentiment options?

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns

I have a sentiment rate functionality. What is the best way to display the options? Start with the positive or negative one?

[image: sentiment rate image]

I have a star rating as well from 1 to 5, if it matters. Is it strange if the star rate is from the lowest value to the highest and the sentiments is from the positive to the negative value?

[Star rating](https://gyazo.com/f35fc41bc46fc8ef2265712592163b31)

Comment: The smiley faces do not have the same kind of ‘direction’ as the stars, so I think the ordering does not have to match the stars. They should instead be easily identifiable as positive or negative, so I would suggest using colour in addition to the mouth orientation, or even make the happy mouth open, so it is also shaped differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, there is no much reasoning against displaying a sentiment rating scale in the order from negative to positive. This way its ordering resonates with the one that most users used to see.

However, the scale should be identifiable even with a superficial glance, so the following colouring may be applied:

- shades of red  - for negative;
- shades of green - for positive.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a star rating as well from 1 to 5 with 5 as the highest rating, so it would be nice to keep the same layout flow for both of rating input either from left to right or vice versa.